# how to use '\n' within text property of mx:TextArea in flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, textarea

As per my observation this does not work in flex4:

```
<mx:TextArea id="taMytext" text="\n hi\n san"/> //use of \n does not work here
<s:Button label="Click it" click="Myfun()" />
```

Using script it's possible:

```
public function Myfun():void
            {
                taMytext.text="hi\n";
                taMytext.text+="san";
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the only way is to use the following:

```
<mx:TextArea horizontalCenter="0" id="taMytext" text="{'\n'} hi{'\n'} san" verticalCenter="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following syntax:

```
<mx:TextArea id="taMytext" text="\n hi{'\n'} san"/>
```

More detailled explaination can be found [on adobe cookbooks](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_Line_Breaks_in_MXML_Attributes-9223.html)

Comment: what is the meaning of &#xd; which can be used instead of {'\n'} ?

Comment: It's the way the carriage return character ('\r') is represented in canonical XML. [More details](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-xml-c14n-19991109.html#charescaping)